# Why does C program skip my if loop for programming raspberrypi?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I am trying to do a c program that programs to raspberrypi to turn on/off/blink the LED diode in a breadboard. There is a button on the breadboard that I use the digitalread function to "click" it. Ideally, the program should work by clicking the button once, the LED will light up. Click again and it will turn off the light. Click once more and it will blink a few times and the loop will repeat. However, when i use this program, it seems like the first 2 if statement are skipped. And when i clicked the button, it only blinks. Does anybody know why?

```
int main (int argc, char **argv){

wiringPiSetupGpio();
int counter=1;
pinMode(PIN_LED, OUTPUT);
pinMode(PIN_BUTTON, INPUT);
printf("LED and button pins have beens setup.\n");

while (1)
{   
    if ((counter==1) && (digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON))) {
        digitalWrite(PIN_LED, HIGH);
        counter++;
    }
    if ((counter==2) && (digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON))){
        digitalWrite(PIN_LED, LOW);
        counter++;
    }
    if ((counter==3) && (digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON))){
        digitalWrite(PIN_LED, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(PIN_LED, LOW);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(PIN_LED, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(PIN_LED, LOW);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(PIN_LED, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(PIN_LED, LOW);
        delay(500);
        counter=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON)` would just test whether the button is currently pressed.  So the first `if` will either do nothing (if the button is not yet pressed), or else turn on the LED - but the first two `if`s will complete so fast that you won't see the result.  If you want to *wait* until the button becomes pressed, you need a loop.  And then you probably want another loop in between to wait until it is released.

Comment: The first two `if`-statements are executed so fast that you do not notice them. If `counter` is `1` and the button pressed, then the first `if`-statement is executed which increases `counter` to `2` and thus the second `if`-statement is executed immediately. To make this work, I think you need to add `else` before the second and third `if`-statement and after processing a button press, you need to wait until the button is released. Otherwise you will execute several actions for the same button press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your while loop in steps:

```
if ((counter==1) && (digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON))) {
        digitalWrite(PIN_LED, HIGH);
        counter++;
    }
```

Initially, counter is 1, but the pin is not pressed, so this won't do anything.

```
    if ((counter==2) && (digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON))){
        // ...
    }
```

counter is not 2, so this won't do anything either.

```
    if ((counter==3) && (digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON))){
        // ...
    }
```

Same here. So nothing will happen as long as the button is not pressed.

Now when you press the button, it gets interesting:

```
if ((counter==1) && (digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON))) {
        digitalWrite(PIN_LED, HIGH);
        counter++;
    }
```

This condition is now satisfied. The LED is turned on and the counter incremented.

```
    if ((counter==2) && (digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON))){
        // ...
    }
```

Now... this is true *as well*. Since the button is still pressed (you can't release it that fast) this is immediately true as well. Now incrementing counter to 3.

```
    if ((counter==3) && (digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON))){
        // ...
    }
```

And now...? Yes. This is *also* true now. So it starts blinking immediately.

What you have to do (for example) is wait for the button to be not pressed after each condition:

```
if ((counter==1) && (digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON))) {
        digitalWrite(PIN_LED, HIGH);
        counter++;
        while (digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON)); // Wait until button depressed.
    }
```

Remark: While this conceptually works, you should consider using events instead. Busy-Waiting is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Thank you all and especially to PMF for the detailed explanation. I tried adding the while (digitalRead(PIN_BUTTON)); and it works now. I will try to make the code more productive